# PHP Regex help, filtering phone numbers

Tags: php, regex

Regex gurus please i want to filter something like 2338034444232, 07065716184,0816272721. Phone numbers separation with comma, i want my final product to be like 2338034444232,2338034444232,2338034444232.

Thanks

Comment: This belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I don't see any logical connection from the first string to the last, except that it's the first number repeated 3 times...

Comment: I don't get what you want ?:o/

Comment: You have to provide us with the **context** which your numbers are in and at least 3 **real examples** and as much information on the numbers as possible (international code, number of digits etc...)

Comment: I want user type any digi into text input then i will format it like 2339033267345. character length will be 13

Comment: Give an example of a user input from a user please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$userinput="
    I believe Mr. Putin's number is 1234567890123 only differing slight
    from mine 1234567890124. I tried calling him 42 times but he won't answer.
    ";

$regex="/[0-9]{13}/";

preg_match_all($regex,$userinput,$out);


foreach($out[0] as $o){

    echo $o;
    echo ", ";
}
```

Now if the user were to call *Mr. Putin* 1234567890124 times you'd have a problem.

Is this the kind of thing your looking for?

Comment: I did this preg_match_all("/([0-9]){11,13}/",$email_address_file, $email_addresses_search_found)

Comment: Well you said that the phone numbers are 13 digits long *only* ... but is your problem solved now?